# Como usar Regex en un if statement

Tags: javascript

Haciendo una función que toma como argumento una `str`, devuelve la `str` con los espacios cambiados por guiones:

```
function urlSlug(title) {
   str = title.toLowerCase();
   arr = str.split(" ");
   definitivestr = arr.join("-");
    return definitivestr
}
```

Por ejemplo `urlSlug("Winter Is Coming")` debe retornar "`winter-is-coming`"

La particularidad es que por ejemplo si se da `urlSlug(" Winter Is  Coming")` la función ya no retorna "`winter-is-coming`" sino "`-winter-is--coming`".

Para lo que he añadido esto:

```
function urlSlug(title) {
   str = title.toLowerCase();
   arr = str.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){if (arr[i] == ""){arr.splice(i,1)}}
   definitivestr = arr.join("-");
    return definitivestr
}
```

Sin embargo todavía no vale, por que si se da otra vez `urlSlug(" Winter Is Coming")` la función todavía no retorna "`winter-is-coming`" sino "`winter-is- coming`".

Así que no se se me ha ocurrido si se puede poner en el `if statement` otro `if` que busque si la "`arr[i]`" tiene `/\W/` pues que borre todo lo que sea `/\W/`

```
function urlSlug(title) {
       str = title.toLowerCase();
       arr = str.split(" ");
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){if (arr[i] == ""){arr.splice(i,1)}
  if ((newnewstr[i]) == /\W/){newnewstr.splice(i,1)}}
       definitivestr = arr.join("-");
        return definitivestr
    }
```

Ya esta ultima si que está mal porque no se como integrar ahí un `Regex`

Comment: Si lo que deseas es eliminar los espacios demás (ya sea al principio, final o entre palabras) puedes aplicarle un `trim()` a cada elemento del  `array`. Es lo que se me ocurre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Javascript tienes [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) para reemplazar caracteres en cadenas, y acepta expresiones regulares. Una solución válida para tu caso es:

```js
function urlSlug(title) {
  str = title.toLowerCase().trim();
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, '-')
}
    
console.log(urlSlug(' Winter      is Coming   '))
```

Explicación:

- Primero pasamos la cadena a minúsculas y con `trim()` eliminamos espacios al inicio y al final.
- `\s` busca cualquier espacio
- `+` significa una o más ocurrencias
- `g` significa "global": si no lo usas, se parará cuando encuentre el primer espacio (lo puedes comprobar tú mismo)

Y para comprobar si una expresión regular se encuentra en una cadena tienes [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). El `if ((newnewstr[i]) == /\W/)`, tal y como lo has puesto, simplemente hace una comparación de valores, y claramente no coinciden porque `newnewstr[i]` es una cadena y `/\W/` es una expresión regular.

Al final con las expresiones regulares es mucha práctica hasta que encuentras la que se adecúa a tus necesidades.